# How to get access_token from AUTH0 NEXT.JS

Tags: next.js, access-token, auth0

I am using Next.js frontend and Auth0 to log in to the user, how can get access_token and console it when the user logs in using Auth0 in my next js application?

access_token which I can send to the backend so the backend can verify with auth0 and allow the frontend to hit other APIs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.